# audit DML changes on any table by an user in oracle

Tags: oracle, eventtrigger

i have a requirement where i need to capture all INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE events by an user schema on any table and log it in the user defined table.

Ive managed to create an unified policy but how do set up my trigger?

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_log_trigger
  2  AFTER INSERT ON AUDSYS.UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5    v_sql_text CLOB;
  6  BEGIN
  7    IF :NEW.unified_audit_policies = 'FME_DML_PLAY'  THEN
  8      v_sql_text := :NEW.sql_text;
  9      INSERT INTO user_audit_log (audit_id, audit_date, os_username, userhost, dbusername, action_name, event_timestamp, sql_text)
 10      VALUES (audit_log_seq.NEXTVAL, SYSTIMESTAMP, :NEW.os_username, :NEW.userhost, :NEW.dbusername, :NEW.action_name, :NEW.event_timestamp, v_sql_text);
 11    END IF;
 12  END;
 13  /
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_log_trigger
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-25001: cannot create this trigger type on this type of view
```

Comment: Trigger for freeware homegrown solution or audit option for Oracle. This question is too broad and is opinion based

Comment: Google "AUDIT" statement in Oracle docs. But if you need to know before/after values,  then lookup triggers.